# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.maps.GeoApiContext$Builder

Tags: java, eclipse, google-maps, gradle

I'm using the [Java library for the Google Maps API](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java) but cannot find the code at runtime. I've added the repository and dependencies to build.gradle as detailed in the readme. Everything compiles fine, the import statement autocompletes, I can open the source code in Eclipse through "View Declaration," and I can see Google Maps in the Java build path.

```
import com.google.maps.GeoApiContext;

// Throws exception!
GeoApiContext.Builder builder = new GeoApiContext.Builder();
```

Why is this library visible at compile time but not runtime?

ETA: The application is packaged as an EAR file and deployed to a web server.

Answer (score 0):

With the scarse details you provided, my guess is that you built a jar file and then ran `java -jar myApplication.jar`.

The default jar file only contains the classes of you own application, and not its dependencies. If you want to make an executable jar, you have several options. Some of the more popular are:

1. Use the [shadow plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/), which will repackage the jar to make it "fat" with all its dependencies.
2. Use the standard [distribution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html) plugin that will create a zip (or tar) of your project and its dependencies. It will also a script for setting the classpath correctly.

Comment: The application is packaged as an EAR file and deployed to a web server.